# Magento 2 : CMS Pages/Blocks and Products Not Loading in Backend

Tags: magento2, product, blocks, nginx, cms-pages

I'm using Magento 2.2.2 with PHP 7.1.1, CentOS 7 and Nginx.

Currently in developer mode, I am working normally in Windows 10 and hosts file changed to the server IP, locally.
After pointing the domain to this server and trying to access it, everything except these section work as intended.

If I still change the hosts file to the server IP, all sections show up as intended.

Pages show the spinning wheel but no content is loaded. No error log whatsoever. No console error in the inspector aswell.

What could be happening here?

Comment: Have you run the deploy command?

Comment: yes, everything has been done correctly prior to this issue. 
My main issue as that I cannot work to solve this problem since there are no errors showing up, thus I have no idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started looking into server problems regarding this issue and found out that PageSpeed for Nginx was causing this issue ( All minify, etc., options on magento2 are disabled ).

Disabling it solved my issue.

I wonder if I can replicate this issue with my exact server configuration on a clean magento 2.2.2 installation and PageSpeed for Nginx on, since I also have Magento 1.9 running on the server with no issues whatsoever regarding this particular module.